# Process.Start(string); - starts process for a few seconds. C#

Tags: c#, process, process.start

I have an Windows 7(x86), and my Console Application(C#).
In my application i need to run a new process.
Application consists from just:

`Process.Start(filename);`

When the App is runing, it creates a new process, but he destroys after few seconds, even not being initializated.
In debug i see this information:

```
"proc.MainModule" threw exception "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"
NativeErrorCode = 299
ExitCode = -3
```

If i run needed application by Windows - it runs.
Please, can anyone help me?

When it Runs as Admin it has same errors.

About  `ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory didn't complete successfully`. I do nothing after `Process.Start();`
This error i can see in debug after `var proc = Process.Start(filename);`.

AOgame.exe - is my executable application. It's an exe file of game Allods.
When i trying to execute other applications they are starting good. I think that it is problem with AOgame.exe. But i don't know how to remove error.

in the properties of AOgame.exe there are no arguments.

I think it's anti-cheat protection. BUT if i try to execute it from cmd-console it will work.

**YES! I found solution! First - create a batch file, wich will execute AOgame.exe Then - execute batch file from my application**
It's strange solution, but it works :D

Comment: Can you show us some code? Error code 299 means that a call to either ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory didn't complete successfully, so knowing what you're trying to do with the new process seems pretty important.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what process you're trying to start?

Comment: By any chance, do you know If those executables you are trying to start are 64 bit or 32 bit? Also, can you also tell us If you can execute those "filename" [in Process.Start(filename)] of their own and get any error?

Comment: I have 32 bit system. And if i run executable by using explorer.exe, it will work. But when i try to execute by my program it fails. So my system is 32 bit and all executables are 32bit too. Or not?
The code is just: Process.Start(filename);
And the process creates for a few seconds, or miliseconds then fails

Comment: Could you also check If your console Application(C#) is run as Admin and still throws the same error?

Comment: @AshishGupta running as Admin didn't help. Same error.

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to invoke some COM objects in the called application...that brings in a whole world of possible downstream side effects in this case. More detail about the called application would be very helpful if not essential in helping further.

Comment: @DavidW AOgame.exe - is executable application. It's an exe file of game Allods.

Comment: Based on the details of AOgame.exe, I suspect you might need to provide some startup parameters or additional information to a ProcessStartInfo structure. Perhaps one of the properties such as UseShellExecute would come into play and affect how the application is launched. Are you sure that the application normally starts with no other parameters, or special environment constraints?

Comment: @DavidW in the properties of AOgame.exe there are no arguments.

Comment: @user1515479 Have you found solution. I have the same issue, just exit code is different. If I want to start "explorer.exe" it works. I try to start a process from ASP.NET MVC that is set as 64bit. And application that I want to strat is aslo 64bit process... What is strange some days it works, and some days not :/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the process needs some files in the working directory?...

try to set the working directory:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("foo.exe");
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\bar";

Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Comment: Perhaps the game has an anti-cheat protection? Can you start the Game directly in a cmd-console and/or with a selfmade batch-file?

Comment: I think it's anti-cheat protection. BUT if i try to execute it from cmd-console it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest that you use a ProcessStartInfo instance with UseShellExecute set to false, as follows:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("AOGame.exe");
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process.Start(processInfo);
```

This forces the startup to be handled directly by the process name supplied in the executable, rather than relying on shell/helper routines. If you can provide any more detail on what the AOGame.exe does internally it could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help.

Comment: Can you provide any more technical guidance as to what AOGame.exe is doing? It would really be helpful.

Comment: As another idea, just to prove we're not chasing the wrong kind of rabbit, could you attempt to invoke a very simple application, such as Notepad, in your startup parameter and ensure it starts properly?

Comment: yes. Other application are working normaly. I don't know what wrong with this AOGame.exe. He executes without parametr when it's from explorer.exe.

Comment: YES! I found solution! 
First - create a batch file, wich will execute AOgame.exe
Then - execute batch file from my application

Comment: But it's not a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working link in your windows startmenu you can try this:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\foo\bar.lnk");
```

... i dont give up :-D

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on it for some time.
and I found out that the debugger actually doesn't understand a string for running a process 
I mean you cannot do this

```
Process.start(path);
```

for instead you can use this code:

```
       string pathak="AOgame.exe";
       string rty = pathak.Remove(pathak.Length - 5);
       string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\";
       Process.Start(path + rty + "exe");
```

Hope this help you.